# Registration response error in network tab

Tags: networking, cors, registration, body-parser, couchdb-mango

Hii I am trying to create a basic application with features of user registration and login

in that, I created node js + express server and connected mango db  too here in the registration form user input details
[image] like name email and password are displaying the server terminal
[image]
but [image]

the network response showing error  i am using cors also

my registration form code :`

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Register() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    async function Registeruser(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                password
            })
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            // Registration successful
            console.log('Registration successful');
        } else {
            // Registration failed
            setError(data.error || 'An error occurred');
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="maindiv">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <p></p>
                <form onSubmit={Registeruser}>
                    <input
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Your Name"
                    />
                    <p></p>
                    <input
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Email"
                    />
                    <p></p>
                    <input
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Password"
                    />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
                {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

and server index.js code

````
  const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

const User = require('./models/user.model');


app.use(cors()); // Use the cors middleware
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://ganeshnandhipati161999:Ganesh123%40%23%24@cluster1ganesh.n9trq4x.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
 
 


  app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
      await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: newPassword,
        })
        res.json({ status: 'ok' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Duplicate email' })
    }
})
 

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  if (user) {
    return res.json({ status: 'ok', user: true });
  } else {
    return res.json({ status: 'error', user: false });
  }
});

app.listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Server started on 1337');
});   
    ```

why it showing like these 

I am expecting user registration and a successful registration and login and details will store in mongo db database
````

Comment: mate, remove you credentials from the code and images

Answer (score 0):

If you see your catch block of this code :

```
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
      await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: newPassword,
        })
        res.json({ status: 'ok' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Duplicate email' })
    }
})
```

Here your code goes into the catch block, and in the catch block, you are sending the response. In this response, you have sent the message "Duplicate email"

I suggest you check in your catch block by checking the error, and what errors you are getting, fixing this will solve your issue.